# How to convert ip configuration from dhcp to static using nmcli?

Tags: redhat, networkmanager

is there a way to use nmcli to convert dhcp acquired IP configuration (IP,Mask,Gateway,DNS) to static configuration?

Preferable in a way that i can use in a script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forget for a second whether or not this is technically possible. This is not something want to do, as you'll be statically-assigning an IP address that is within the pool of IP addresses that your DHCP server is managing. At best, this situation will cause confusion and lack of clarity in your overall network configuration and at worst, could cause lack of connectivity on the network.

Consider two other options:

1. Create a DHCP reservation for your host.
2. Assign a static IP address outside of your DHCP pool.

Comment: Ofcourse i'm aware of that but this is simple/clever/hack (but not the best) way to give ip address and to document ip allocation.
Actually different script is creating dhcp reservation for this address.
I need static configuration to be independent of dhcp server. DHCP server is needed to give IP to new server and to review ip allocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
nmcli con add con-name "ens18" ifname ens32 type ethernet ip4 xxx.xxx.120.44/24 gw4 xxx.xxx.120.1
nmcli con mod "ens18" ipv4.dns "xxx.xxx.120.1,8.8.8.8"
nmcli con up "ens18" iface ens18
```

This will add and run static IP. You can add staic IP to existing connection  by using:

```
nmcli con mod "ens18" +ip4 xxx.xxx.120.44/24 +gw4 xxx.xxx.120.1 +ipv4.dns '8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1'
```